# How to parse other attributes in custom rust proc_macro attribute?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I am writing a proc_macro attribute that add fields to a struct and also implement my trait (and other by adding a `#[derive(...)]`) to the expanded struct

Here a simplified version of what I want to do:

```rust
#[foo("some value")]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    bar: u32,
}
```

After expansion:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, Serialize)]
struct A {
    foo: u64
    bar: u32,
}

impl FooTrait for A {
    ...
}
```

How can I parse the derive attribute in order to add the `Debug` trait with all the rest of the trait that I add with the `foo` proc_macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `syn`, inspect and change `ItemStruct::attrs`:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

use proc_macro2::{Delimiter, TokenTree};
use quote::ToTokens;
use syn::parse::Parser;
use syn::punctuated::Punctuated;

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn foo(
    attr: proc_macro::TokenStream,
    input: proc_macro::TokenStream,
) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let mut input = syn::parse_macro_input!(input as syn::ItemStruct);

    let mut all_derived_traits = HashSet::new();
    for i in 0..input.attrs.len() {
        if !input.attrs[i].path.is_ident("derive") {
            continue;
        }

        let derive = input.attrs.remove(i);
        let mut tokens = derive.tokens.clone().into_iter();
        match [tokens.next(), tokens.next()] {
            [Some(TokenTree::Group(group)), None]
                if group.delimiter() == Delimiter::Parenthesis =>
            {
                match Punctuated::<syn::Path, syn::Token![,]>::parse_terminated
                    .parse2(group.stream())
                {
                    Ok(derived_traits) => all_derived_traits.extend(derived_traits),
                    Err(e) => return e.into_compile_error().into(),
                }
            }
            _ => {
                return syn::Error::new_spanned(derive, "malformed derive")
                    .into_compile_error()
                    .into()
            }
        }
    }
    
    all_derived_traits.extend([
        syn::parse_quote!(Default),
        syn::parse_quote!(Serialize),
    ]);
    
    let all_derived_traits = all_derived_traits.into_iter();
    input.attrs.push(syn::parse_quote! {
        #[derive( #(#all_derived_traits),* )]
    });
    
    input.into_token_stream().into()
}
```

First we collect all `derive()` attributes in a hashset, so we won't generate the derives if they're already there. This logic is not perfect: for example, we won't identify `std::default::Default` as the same as `Default`. But it should be enough. Then we add our traits and re-generate the derives. Note that mutliple `#[derive()]` lines are unified and traits may be ordered, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you! Very informative answer. However it looks like  syn::Path does not implement Eq, so inserting (extending in this case) Path in an HashSet doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Jil It does, but you have to turn the `extra-traits` feature.